# Wifi suddenly going off periodically

Tags: 16.04, wireless, iwlwifi

My wifi connection is connection is being interrupted constantly on my Ubuntu laptop.

It still keeps connected to the network but isn't able to reach the internet.

This happens both with the internal network card (*Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)*) and my USB external wifi card (*Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]*).

This is the relevant error found when running dmesg:

```
[ 9017.742536] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[ 9017.742560] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[ 9017.742561] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
```

I have tried everything I've found Googling (mostly on the Arch Linux forums) but nothing has worked for me at this point.

Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One possible source of the problem is excessive heat, because of Summer air temperature... Try turning off the computer and only turning on at night, when the air temperature is lower. If does not work the same, forget the temperature issue!